# Execute multi command in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I tried to run multi-windows commands inside one opened window from a batch file.
I want the opened command window to perform two things in sequence:

1. Switch volume
2. Direct to a directory in that volume.

Here's what I wrote:

```
start cmd /k C: && cd 'C:\Program Files (x86)\aaa\'
```

However, this only switches volume. The second thing is not executed.
Can anyone please show me the way?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have at least 2 options...:
1st, make sure your && is passed to new cmd...

```
start cmd /k "C: && CD c:\temp"
```

2nd, use /d switch on cd to "get there" in one step...

```
start cmd /k cd /d c:\temp
```

KR
Bartek

Answer (score 0):

What don't you just open your cmd at the needed directory? Like^

```
start /dc:\temp cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change directory to another drive you can use

`cd /d C:\`

but if your changing directory within the same drive you shouldn't need to switch drives, just change to that directory:

`cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\aaa"`

Remember to put quotes around paths with spaces, possibly why your command didn't work earlier.

Also, you shouldn't really need `start` and `cmd`. What you doing doesn't really need to be threaded as such. If it's a batch file you can just use `pause` at the end instead of using `cmd /k`.

Your complete batch file would then look like this:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\aaa"
pause >nul
```

or using `cmd /k` for one line (in case of command line use):

```
cmd /k cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\aaa"
```

Hope this helps!